# Python: Log into common file

Tags: python, logging

I have a python project with various nested modules. I would like to have a `setup_logger` function, which is called at the beginning of each file to set up the logger

```py
from _base import setup_logger
logger = setup_logger()
```

and auto-generates the name of the log file after the file name of the main calling script.
For example, I would like to be able to execute the script *myscript.py* in the terminal, and this should log to a file called *myscript_<proc_id>.log*. In that log file should be written by all modules that will be called during the execution.
That is, my desired output is a single log file (named after the main caller, e.g. *myscript_45469.log* for *myscript.py*) and the log strings as follows:

```sh
2021-05-15 21:06:15: myscript[45469]    INFO : A log message from myscript.py
2021-05-15 21:06:16: submodule_1[45469] INFO : A log message from submodule_1.py
2021-05-15 21:06:17: submodule_2[45469] INFO : A log message from submodule_2.py
```

In my terminal, this is exactly what I get. However, the output is still written to separate files with only the messages of the respective module in each file:

```sh
$ ls
myscript_45469.log  submodule_1_45469.log  submodule_2_45469.log
$ cat submodule_1_45469.log
2021-05-15 21:06:16: submodule_1[45469] INFO : A log message from submodule_1.py
```

So far, my `setup_logger` function looks like follows:

```py
# _base.py
from pathlib import Path
import logging
import os

def setup_logger(name=None, level="INFO", logfile=True):
    frame = inspect.stack()[1]
    caller_filename = frame[0].f_code.co_filename
    caller_filename = Path(caller_filename).stem

    if not name:
        name = caller_filename

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(os.getenv('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO').upper())

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(name)s[%(process)d] %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    if logfile:
        logfile = f'{name}_{os.getpid()}.log'
        fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        fh.setLevel(os.getenv('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO').upper())
        logger.addHandler(fh)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    return logger
```

The function then gets called at the beginning of each (sub)module:

```py
# submodule_1 or submodule_2, etc
from _base import *
logger = setup_logger()

logger.info("A log message from submodule_1")
```

How can I achieve my desired goal without hardcoding the filename in the logger setup?
I already scraped through quite some posts here on stackoverflow and many logging tutorials, but I couldn't find a solution so far.
Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with `logging`, you should rely to [hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects).

Let's assume the tree structure of your project is set like this:

```
project/
├─ myscript.py
├─ package/
│  ├─ submodule.py
```

In your submodule you will need to get the module name logger; in this case is `package.submodule`.

```py
# submodule.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # package.submodule
```

After that, heading to `myscript`, you need to setup the logger the way you want it to work.

```py
# myscript.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("package")  # intercept all "package" loggers
logger.setLevel("<your_level>")

formatter = logging.Formatter("<your_format>")

sh = logging.StreamHandler()
fh = logging.FileHandler("package.log")

for handler in (sh, fh):
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Setupping your environment like this, all the loggers referenced in the execution will behave like you want them to do, so logging both to console and (same) log file, with a common format and a common log level.

If your submodule is in module-level (so there is no `package`), you should `getLogger()` - it will pick the root logger.
In either case it will work as intended.

Comment: Hi crissal, thanks for your answer.
What I was looking or hoping for is having a function that sets up my logger for every file in which I call it. It should, hereby, also auto-generate the name of the log file based on the name of the file, which I am executing in the terminal, such that all logs from all submodules that are called during that execution are written to the same log file. I get this result only if I hardcode the name of the log file as you did in your example ("package.log"). Desired would be a dynamic naming of the log file.

Comment: In other words; I would like my messages from submodules to get piped through to the main logger (of the executed script) and then get written into the log file I specified for that main logger.

Comment: `"package.log"` is just a string; you can call it however you want, like `f"{__name__}_{os.getpid()}.log"`, so it will have the module name (myscript) and the process pid